# ScrollController with flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have this class:

```
class MyView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      title: Text("My Page"),
      body: BlocProvider<MyBloc>(
        builder: (context) => MyBloc()..add(OnOpen()),
        child: BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyBlocState>(
          builder: (context, state) => _buildView(state, context)
        )
      )
      ...
    );
  }

  Widget _buildView(MyBlocState state, BuildContext context) {
    if (state is MainState) {
      ScrollController sc = ScrollController(
        initialScrollOffset: 0,
        keepScrollOffset: true
      );

      ListView lv = ListView.separated(
        controller: sc,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        ...
      );

      if (state.hasNewItem && sc.hasClients) {
        sc.animateTo(
          ...
        );
      }

      return lv;
    }

    return _loadingScreen();
  }
}
```

Basically, what I want is to scroll the listview when new item is added, however, `sc.hasClients` always returns **false** since there's no attached scroll views yet.

There's a way to this without using delay (using delay sounds hacky e.e)?

Comment: Does that code even work? You use BlocBuilder with the same context as you use BlocProvider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I just used `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`, like this:

```
if (state.hasNewItem) {
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    sc.animateTo(
      ...
    );
  });
}
```

Got this from a response at github of flutter bloc, [here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/63#issuecomment-455744696).